# How do you declare a FOR EACH loop in MS Access database relationships in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, foreach

I have a database for tracking family passes and member usage at our pool. I have 3 tables, one for family details, one for every individual member, and one for tracking check-ins.

There's a relationship that connects each individual record is appropriate family pass. Each individual is issued a pass that is scanned by a barcode scanner and checks them in using a simple form, I want to write a loop for a button that will check in every member of the family when they show up together, instead of having each individual scan their card.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "CheckIn"

Dim person As ?
Dim family As ?

FOR EACH person IN family

    Forms!CheckIn![PASSHOLDER] = Me![BARCODE]
    Forms!CheckIn![CHECKINTIME] = Now()
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

NEXT

DoCmd.Close acForm, "CheckIn", acSaveYes
```

Problem is I don't know enough about VBA to figure out how to accomplish this. Do I need to create an array first? How do I prepare my data from my relationships in order to execute my loop?

Comment: `For Each Object in Objects` dim as Object

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the normalized structure below between tables, simply use SQL. Recall forms are just visual representation of tables usually for data management (add, edit, save, delete). Since you know what to *add*, automate the data entry with backend querying.

Family Details

```
FamilyID ...
```

Individual Members

```
MemberID, FamilyID ...
```

CheckIns

```
MemberID, PASSHOLDER, CHECKINTIME ...
```

So in VBA, if a family checks in press the button and run an append query which after refresh will show as individual records in the *CheckIn* form. This assumes some *Family* identifier textbox resides on form to be used in `WHERE` clause and in this case make it an unbound textbox including bar code since these fields will not be used for *user data entry* but *SQL-automated data entry*. Even consider an unbound form apart from actual *CheckIn* for this particular automation.

```vb
Private Sub FamilyCheckinCommand_Click()

    If Not IsNull(Forms!CheckIn![FamilyID]) Then
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO CheckIn (MemberID, PASSHOLDER, CHECKINTIME)" _
                   & " SELECT m.MemberID,'" & Forms!CheckIn![BarCode] & "', Now()" _
                   & " FROM IndividualMembers m" _
                   & " WHERE m.FamilyID = " & Forms!CheckIn![FamilyID]

        ' RUNS QUERY
        CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

        ' REFRESHES FORM
        Me.Form.Requery
    Else
        Msgbox "Please enter a family!", vbExclamation, "MISSING FAMILY"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this? It may work :) (without the rest of the code and not knowing what exactly is family it is hard to say):

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "CheckIn"

Dim person As variant
Dim family As variant

'you should assign person to something actually.

    FOR EACH person IN family

        Forms!CheckIn![PASSHOLDER] = Me![BARCODE]
        Forms!CheckIn![CHECKINTIME] = Now()
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

    NEXT

    DoCmd.Close acForm, "CheckIn", acSaveYes
```

This is how you iterate over a collection:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0e76axa(v=vs.100).aspx